# How does one add a shape to the Google Maps API v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, svg

[The shapes supported by Google Maps API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes) are Polylines, Polygons, Rectangles and Circles.  The standard answer to any questions about extending these is to use Polylines.  This works well if you aren't drawing curves.  However if all you want to do is draw an arc, the choice of increment becomes a trade-off between good representation at high zoom levels and usability at low zoom levels.  This is because if you zoom in on a curve with a coarse increment, it ceases looking like a curve but rather an angular polyline.  If you then fix that by using a fine increment, when you zoom out, you are drawing so many line segments that the user experience becomes unacceptably slow.

SVG supports arcs.  Since the existing API v3 shapes are realized in SVG primitives, it seems it should be feasible for the user of the API v3 to implement other shapes in terms of  SVG primitives.  In particular, since there is already a circle shape supported by v3 it should be straight forward to implement an arc.

Has anyone extended API v3 shapes using SVG primitives in such a manner?

If not, is there any reasonable way of doing so?